# Object function is stripping duplicate values

Tags: javascript

I am running this function to build an array of objects for chartJS:

```js
//create object from item verts
function creatVerticalObj(arr) {
  var verticalObj = {};
  for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    verticalObj[arr[i]] = (verticalObj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return verticalObj;
}

var getLabels = Object.keys(creatVerticalObj(itemFilters));
var getColorValues = Object.keys(creatVerticalObj(itemColor));
var getValues = Object.values(creatVerticalObj(itemCount));
```

Then in chartJS I am running this for data:

```js
data: {
  datasets: [{
    data: getValues,
    backgroundColor: getColorValues,
  }],
  labels: getLabels
},
```

I know the arrays I am feeding into the function have the same number of items in them. There are 19 in each...yet it only actually builds 7 objects.

I know some many of the values are duplicates (they are numbers). I am thinking somehow my logic is removing values if they are duplicates...I need to resolve this.

Comment: You have odd loop syntax. Why use `for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++)` instead of `for (var i = 0, i < arr.length; i++)`? Why introduce the variable j?

Comment: @csm_dev It's a common idiom, to cache the length instead of doing a property lookup each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your arrays have distinct values? You're building the new object using the value of the array as the key, so if they don't have distinct values, you'll end up clobbering those keys.

```
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    verticalObj[arr[i]] = (verticalObj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
```

For example, if your array = [1, 2, 1, 2], the first iteration will set verticalObj[1] = 2, the second time through verticalObj[2] = 2 and the third time through verticalObj[1] = 2. In the end, you'll end up with an object like:

```
{
   1: 2,
   2: 3
}
```

I think what you want is something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    verticalObj[i] = (arr[i] || 0) + 1;
}
```

(Getting rid of extra clutter in your for loop, too, since you're not using the `j` variable.)

Comment: Actually, you'll end up with {'1': 2, '2': 2} since the verticalObj[arr[i]] won't be defined on the first two iterations through.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will put duplicate values into a count, so if you have 7 values, it should look something like this:

```
{
  1: 3,
  2: 5,
  3: 5,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 3
}
```

Where the numbers on the right should add up to your number of input values (19 from what you said).

If that's not your desired behavior, giving an example input and output would be helpful.